# Sorting , searching a dictionary in C#

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, dictionary

I have a dictionary, Dictionary listOfProducts.
This listOfProducts can have hundreds of products.
string key is the product number
I want to get some specific products by product number(key),
I have a list of keys e.g. 64290,64287,59261,50990,50975,50897,68494,68495,51015,68493
the resulting dictionary should have only items with the above keys and in the same order,
Any idea how can i do this. ?
If there is any order data structure that can work better in this scenario?

Here is the complete scenario :

Here is the complete scenario : I get an xml from server with the product info
the formate of this XMl is

```
<key>64285</key><string>productname[SEPERATOR]product description</string>  <key>64285</key><string>productname[SEPERATOR]product description</string><key>64285</key><string>productname[SEPERATOR]product description</string>
```

Now this XML does not contain all the prodcut detaqils (e.g. this product does not have the Product Rating , or Product Color)
I need to sort and search by Product rating and Product Color. 
For that i get another XMl wich has the product keys order by Rating .

```
<dict>  <key>rating</key>   <string>64285,68495,68494,64228,68491.......</string> <key>price</key>   <string>68493,64234,50863,64236,64223,....</string> </dict>
```

Similary i have to Search for the Product with the Color "White"
For this i get XMl with the list the products that are in white color,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Dictionary does not have an order. Maybe you can make a List which contains the elements in order.

```
List<Product> result = new List<Product>();
var keys = new [] {64290,64287,59261,50990,50975,50897,68494,68495,51015,68493};
foreach (var key in keys)
{
    result.Add(listOfProducts[key]);
}
return result;
```

Comment: Thanks Sjoerd ,But i was in search of some built in method? I mean by using LINQ or some other technique

Comment: var result = keys.Select(key => listOfProducts[key]).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx)?

Alternativly, I don't think you can rely on the order of items in the dictionary, but you could implement [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx) or [IComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) interfaces in your object, then use those to sort and search.

or try a Queue?

Can you add more detail to the context of your question, I would make it easier if we knew why you were trying to achieve what you are asking for.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean in the exact order you have in your question?

Comment: This won't work. The keys have a specific order, but they are not sorted.

Comment: Yes, I thought so. I think you need to use a different data structure. I've updated my answer. If you want them in a particular order, you will need to use a list or a queue I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a separate Array/List `var keyList = new List<int>();` to store the keys in the order you want, that way you can iterate through the `keyList` and do a lookup for the value in the original Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a [Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) is probably the collection you're looking for, since you're mapping one key to many possible values (if I read correctly).

You can sort the entries however you want when creating the lookup, or when you're retrieving the values out of it.

Edit:

Here is an example:

```
var Products = new [] 
{
    new { Key = "64290", Name = "P1" },
    new { Key = "64290", Name = "P2" },
    new { Key = "64287", Name = "P3" },
    new { Key = "59261", Name = "P4" },
    new { Key = "59261", Name = "P5" },
    new { Key = "64290", Name = "P6" },
    new { Key =" 64290", Name = "P7" },
    new { Key = "51015", Name = "P8" },
    new { Key = "51015", Name = "P9" }
};

Lookup<string,string> products = ( Lookup<string,string> ) Products.ToLookup
(
    p => p.Key, p => p.Name
);

foreach( IGrouping<string,string> g in products )
{
    Console.WriteLine( g.Key );

    foreach( string product in g )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( String.Concat( "\t", product ) );
    }
}
```

Output:

64290
  P1
  P2
  P6
  P7
64287
  P3
59261
  P4
  P5
51015
  P8
  P9